# Where to close Connection using Connection Pooling in HTTP Servlets

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

Which one is better approach?

a)Get connection from Connection Pool at the beginning of doXXX() method and close at the end.

Use this connection throughout doXXX() method. This way it will fetch connection only once from the connection pool but Connection will be open for the whole time it takes to execute doXXX().

b)Get connection from Connection Pool for each db operation and close.

It will fetch connection from the connection pool for every db operation but will be closed immediately.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "JDBC servlet"; those are separate entities entirely. If you have obtained a connection from a connection pool, let the pool handle it.

Comment: It's HTTP Servlets.. Yes connection pool is already there..

Comment: What's the downside to b? It's so popular Tomcat ships with a JDBC connection pool out-of-the-box.

Comment: Just that in option 1 it will get connection only once at the beginning and all db requests will be processed using this same connection.. What's the overhead for getting connection from connection pool..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. Getting a connection from the pool, worst case could result in the expensive creation of a new connection which might be slow. Between DB calls, how long is it going to be doing stuff? In general, releasing after each operation will slow things down for the specific process, but speed things up for other processes, and vice versa. You only really have to worry about this under massive load.

Comment: Let's say 100-200 concurrent requests all time... doXXX() might take few ms to process for each web request.. For each web request, 4-5 db request are done..

Comment: It probably doesn't matter that much either way, but I'd guess it is slightly better to go with option B IMO. It's more scalable if your load doubles for example.